# Differential equation $f'''(x)=-f(x)$ with restriction using power series

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Using power series, Prove the existence of a $C^3$ function (continuously differentiable 3 times) $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'''(x)=-f(x)$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=1$.

I'm kind of new in this so I think I messed up the indexes while differentiating the power series because I didn't achieve anything solid. any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's not that difficult... just write

$$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2!}f''(0)+\frac{x^3}{3!}f'''(0)+\frac{x^4}{4!}f^{(4)}(0)+\cdots$$
You have the explicit initial conditions for the first three terms, for the rest, you just notice that $f'''(0)=-f(0)=-1$ and if you differentiate again, you get $f^{(4)}(x)=-f'(x)$ and in general $f^{(n)}=-f^{(n-3)}$. You see that if the function was continuously differentiable $3$ times, then it's continuously differentiable an infinite number of times, because higher derivatives are proportional to the lower derivatives (which are continuous by definition). You also get the power series explicitly:
$$f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+\cdots$$
Of course, the differential equation is linear so you can also solve it explicitly with a sum of exponential functions:

$$f(x)=Ae^{-x}+e^{x/2}(B\cos \frac{\sqrt3 x}{2}+C\sin \frac{\sqrt3 x}{2})$$
where $A$, $B$, $C$ can be determined from the initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain how you solved the linear equation to the sum of exponential function? Or direct me to a good source?

Comment: Linear differential equations with constant coefficients can be solved by plugging in $e^{kx}$ and solving the characteristic polynomial for $k$ (which may include complex roots, as in our case - then the Euler equation can get you back to trig functions). A general solution is a superposition of all (in this case 3) possible solutions. Special care is needed if roots are degenerate.

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work using the series, define $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i$$ The initial conditions $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=1$ give $a_0=1$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=\frac 12$.

For the remaining, diffrentiating three times $$f'''(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i(i-1)(i-2) a_i x^{i-3}$$ and the differential equation write $$f'''(x)+f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty i(i-1)(i-2) a_i x^{i-3}+\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i=0$$ Now, setting to $0$ the coefficient of any term $x^k$ gives the recurrence relation $$a_k=-\frac{a_{k-3}}{ k(k-1)(k-2) }$$ from which the power series already given by orion.

Comment: From $a_2$ compute $a_3$ then $a_4$ and observe that $a_n$ is a factorial multiplied by $\pm 1$. You just have $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ with the recurrence relation for the $a_i$'s.

Comment: Arrived to $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^na_0}{(3n)!}x^{3n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^na_1}{(3n+1)!}x^{3n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^na_2}{(3n+2)!}x^{3n+2}$. and how do I turn it to exponential equation?